# How to push SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, safari, ios9

2 strange things happen when I try to push Safari ViewController:

1. Its adress bar with Done button is placed below my Navigation Bar;
2. Delegate method safariViewControllerDidFinish: does not get called when I press back button.

I don't think Apple would approve of this behavoir, so:

Is there a way to push Safari ViewController without these problems?

Comment: It is not stated in the documenting, but you can only present the view modally. You should not push in  a navigation controller.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Do not push a SFSafariViewController with the `pushViewController:animated:` method, instead, use the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method.

The Safari view controller will be presented with a standard *push* animation.

Comment: That's so weird.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to rckoenes comment the only other option i see is to hide the navigation bar when presenting an SFSafariViewController

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func openBrowser(sender: AnyObject) {
        let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: "http://your.url")!)
        safariViewController.delegate = self

        // hide navigation bar and present safari view controller
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController?.pushViewController(safariViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        // pop safari view controller and display navigation bar again
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: The push seems to work fine, but the SFSafariViewController is dismissing the presented view controller, any way to avoid it?