# SFSafariViewController NOT fullscreen / content presented on top

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm making a very simple app for a demo and am trying to present a webpage using `SFSafariViewController` (I need to use `SF` versus `WKWebView` so to be able to access cookies).

I would really like to present the `User` with some `UI buttons`, but I've been unable to pull it off.

I tried this snippet (placed in the completion callback of `presentViewController()`:

```
let width: CGFloat = 66
let x: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width - width

// It can be any overlay. May be your logo image here inside an imageView.
let overlay = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: 20, width: width, height: 44))
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
svc.view.addSubview(overlay)
```

... outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813129/sfsafariviewcontroller-hide-navigation-bar).  In their case, they're attempting to cover the reload button with a small view.  Regardless of the use-case, for me the view immediately disappears when I load `SFSafariViewController` (I can see it for a moment and it disappears).

I was thinking about presenting the button in an `.OverContext` modal, but then the User would be unable to interact with the `SFSafariViewController`, which also doesn't work.

Here's essentially what I'm after (pardon the gross, quick mockup) ... basically, SafariViewController with a view presented over it (see bottom) ... the transparency is just to show that it's being presented over Safari).

[image]

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wkwebview is hiding cookies from you?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out ... there's likely some slight race condition going on that was preventing the recommended "draw a rectangle" code from working as desired.  What I did:

- Subclassed `SFSafariWebViewController`
- In `viewDidAppear`, implemented a slight delay using `NSTimer` that draws any additional view elements

This also ended up helping me hide the status bar, which was giving me issues (see mockup).

Here's the relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class MySafariVC: SFSafariViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        var frame = self.view.frame
        let OffsetY: CGFloat  = 44
        frame.origin = CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y - OffsetY)
        frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height + (1 * OffsetY))
        self.view.frame = frame

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "drawNavBar", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print("i laid out my subviews")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func drawNavBar() {
        let height: CGFloat = 44
        let y: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height - height

        // It can be any overlay. May be your logo image here inside an imageView.
        let overlay = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: height))
        overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9)
        self.view.addSubview(overlay)
    }
}
```