# How to hide the done button and search bar in SafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm using `SafariViewController`to display a webpage, and rather than the default "done" button I push from my app's `NavigationController` to preserve my nav stack and back arrow.  However, I need to hide the default Done button and search bar on the `SafariViewController`.  Is that possible yet? See my code and screen shot below...

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: pinterestSafariURL)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
```

[image]

note:  linking to this question, but the answer is a hack whereas I was looking for a solution using SafariViewController API : [SFSafariViewController: Hide navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813129/sfsafariviewcontroller-hide-navigation-bar?rq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SFSafariViewController/initWithURL:) on `SFSafariViewController`, there does not appear to be a publicly-accessible way to hide either the Done button or the URL bar. Apple suggests that you use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKWebView) if you need a custom browser interface.

There's a [AppCoda tutorial on WKWebView](http://www.appcoda.com/webkit-framework-intro/) that shows you how to create a `ViewController` with an embedded `WKWebView`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I have found as well.  Easy one =)

Answer (score 1):

Brace yourself for ugliness and brittleness:

```
extension MyViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
{
    func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool)
    {
        let f = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20),
                       size: CGSize(width: 90, height: 44))
        let uglyView = UIView(frame: f)
        uglyView.backgroundColor = svc.view.backgroundColor
        controller.view.addSubview(uglyView)
    }
}
```

obviously origin y needs fixin' for iPhone X for this to work more or less.

UPD: Sharon implies down below (in the comments) that such a hackery
is likely to cause the app rejected by apple.

I'd love to see Apple fix this with .none done button styling
available in iOS 14.

Comment: according to the docs:
In accordance with App Store Review Guidelines, this view controller must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller may not be hidden or obscured by other views or layers. Additionally, an app may not use SFSafariViewController to track users without their knowledge and consent.

Comment: So you could have made an answer of your own. A compact one saying: "You can not"