# Hide share options in Safari View Controller

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is there any way to hide the share option in Safari View Controller, which is coming by default?. I am trying to hide the extra options which are given by default with the Safari View Controller but not able to do so.

Let me know if anybody knows about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the done button and search bar in SafariViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612960/how-to-hide-the-done-button-and-search-bar-in-safariviewcontroller)

Comment: Its not a duplicate of your answer, I am asking about the options which are given on the bottom nav bar, which is go to safari and share icon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`SFSafariViewController` is not meant for customizations. Even Apple documentation says to use [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) if you want to customise the look and feel of safari view controller.

*From Apple documentation*

> ## Choosing the Best Web Viewing Class
>
> If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet,
>   use the SFSafariViewController class. If your app customizes,
>   interacts with, or controls the display of web content, use the 
>   WKWebView  class. When you adopt SFSafariViewController and a user
>   presses a link to peek at and then pop to the link’s destination, the
>   user views web content from within your app. Tapping Done, the user
>   returns to the view controller that was displayed before the web
>   content was loaded. When you instead use the WKWebView class, Peek and
>   Pop sends the user to Safari by default.

On the other hand, `SFSafariViewController` does provide some kind of UI customization. You can only change the `preferredBarTintColor` and `prefererredControlTintColor`. iOS 11 has new option to set initial configuration by using `@NSCopying var configuration: SFSafariViewController.Configuration { get }` but sadly that will not help you either

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, this clears my doubt.